# WKWebView JavaScript communication on page load

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

***EDIT***

The below examples **DO** work. I was making a silly mistake and not calling the correct page in my web app. I'll leave this here for anybody else looking for how to do what I am doing.

---

I have Native -> WKWebView JavaScript communication working for my project with the exception of one thing: I am unable to have a `postMessage()` call be recognized when my web page loads.

I have added a message handler named "contentLoaded" that I'm trying to trigger like this from my webview:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.contentLoaded.postMessage("content has loaded");
});
```

and I has also tried:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.contentLoaded.postMessage("content has loaded");
});
```

Additionally, I'm actually using Vue.js so I've also tried to hook into Vue's `created()` and `mounted()` hooks like this:

```
mounted() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.contentLoaded.postMessage("content has loaded");    
}
```

or this:

```
mounted() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.contentLoaded.postMessage("content has loaded");    
}
```

None of these actually trigger the "contentLoaded" message handler.

However, I **can** trigger the message handler if I make some interaction with the web page, for example:

```
// This works!
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   window.webkit.messageHandlers.contentLoaded.postMessage("content has loaded");  
})
```

The Swift side of my code is below. Any advice here?

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()

        contentController.add(self, name: "contentLoaded")

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.userContentController = contentController
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://example.com")
        var myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}

extension MainViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("received")

        if message.name == "contentLoaded", let messageBody = message.body as? String {
            print(messageBody)
        }
    }
}

extension MainViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("didFinish navigation")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("didStartProvisionalNavigation")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` method as your callback for when the window loads, in place of a javascript callback?

Swift usually isn't communicative with the window in WKWebView until it's fully loaded - at which point the `didFinish` method is the first thing called. Assuming you just need to know when the window/content is loaded, I would use that delegate method over JS.

**Edit:** If you need to retrieve some kind of data from the browser when the web page loads, you could call a Javascript method from the `didFinish` block that returns it, assuming you've written such a Javascript method to do so.

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("getData()", completionHandler: { (data, error) in
        if let data = data {
            print("Received: ", data)
        }
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes. I tried to trigger a JavaScript event from `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` back to the WebView that would then trigger the `contentLoaded` message handler to then send back to the Native App with, but that didn't work either. My use case is that I want to send data from the webview to the native app so I can use it to customize some of the UI.

Comment: Typically what I do in this situation is just use `webView.evaluateJavaScript` in the `didFinish` block and then call some Javascript method that returns the data I need, then process it as a response. Is this local content in the browser that you have access to? Edit: Edited my answer with code above.

Comment: When I attempt that I get: `Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=5 "JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type}`. What does my return have to look like on the JavaScript side? I'm trying to return an object or a string.

Comment: Swift won't recognize javascript objects. Strings are fine. If you want to send an object, you could either try to convert it to a string in JS and interpret that into an object in swift, or use JSON. Swift can turn JSON into a dictionary or decode it into objects with the [Codable API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types), which I strongly recommend

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. My code actually was working, but I had a really dumb oversight and wasn't calling the correct page in my application. I've added a note to my original post.

Comment: Ah, I see. And no problem! Hopefully I was helpful in some way lol